# org.apache.avro.ipc.generic.GenericRequestor cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.generic.IndexedRecord

Tags: java, avro

I am newer to avro. I want to test avro-rpc, and write some code using avro-1.7.5.jar, avro-ipc-1.7.5 and avro-tools-1.7.5.jar.
When I run the test code, I get the exception below:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.ipc.generic.GenericRequestor cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.generic.IndexedRecord
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.getField(GenericData.java:576)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.getField(GenericData.java:591)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeField(GenericDatumWriter.java:112)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:104)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:66)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:58)
    at org.apache.avro.ipc.generic.GenericRequestor.writeRequest(GenericRequestor.java:85)
    at org.apache.avro.ipc.Requestor$Request.getBytes(Requestor.java:473)
    at org.apache.avro.ipc.Requestor.request(Requestor.java:147)
    at org.apache.avro.ipc.Requestor.request(Requestor.java:101)
    at org.apache.avro.ipc.generic.GenericRequestor.request(GenericRequestor.java:58)
    at avro.rpc.Client.sendMessage(Client.java:49)
    at avro.rpc.Client.run(Client.java:60)
    at avro.rpc.Client.main(Client.java:79)
```

I cannot figure it out that are there some bugs in avro-1.7.5 or some configuration should I do to make it work !
All advise greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed the same error I have had for over a day! However, my case was slightly different since mine was related to a MapReduce job.

I still think, this may be of help.

Here are the major things:

- When deploying, do not include any avro jobs in the jar you are building.
- include all your avro jars on hadoop classpath on your cluster
- add all the avro jars to "-libjars" as a commandline parameter (not sure if this applies to your case)